# Dependency Injection is not working in play framework

Tags: java, dependency-injection, playframework, guice, morphia

## Module Class

```java
public class MorphiaModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
   bind(PlayMorphia.class).asEagerSingleton();
 }
}
```

## PlayMorphia

```java
@Singleton
public class PlayMorphia {

MongoClient mongo = null;
Datastore datastore = null;
Morphia morphia = null;

@Inject
public PlayMorphia(ApplicationLifecycle lifecycle, Environment env, Configuration config) {
    try {
        configure(config, env.classLoader(), env.isTest());  // Method calling to get the config
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    lifecycle.addStopHook(()->{
        if (env.isTest()) {
            mongo().close();
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
    });
 }
}
```

In My `application.conf`, I mentioned the correct package/path name for `Module` class i.e.

```java
play.modules.enabled  += "configuration.MorphiaModule"
```

I followed the **Play framework** official doc on Eager Binding: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Eager-bindings

At compile time, I am getting this:

> CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) No implementation for play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle was bound.
>       while locating play.inject.ApplicationLifecycle
>       for the 1st parameter of configuration.PlayMorphia. . 
>       (PlayMorphia.java:28)
>       at configuration.MorphiaModule.configure(MorphiaModule.java:24) (via 
>       modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule ->
>       configuration.MorphiaModule)

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Where did you put the `play.modules.enabled` line? Into `reference.conf`?

Comment: @cbley I added into `application.conf`. BTW I have already tried with `reference.conf`. I got the same result

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem, but for me it works as expected. In order to reproduce this you should show us a complete minimal example project. You left out important parts in your question, like Play version, SBT version, build files, import statements.

Comment: @cbley This is really strange! I also tried with a new project and it works for me. After that, I moved everything from my old project to the new one. New project is working for me but not the old one.